# CCNA Question: What field is consisted of 6 bytes in the field identification frame in IEEE 802.1Q?

Tags: networking, cisco

I got the below question in CCNA Dumps:

> What field is consisted of 6 bytes in the field identification frame in IEEE 802.1Q?

The answer was SA, however the in the choices there were DA. Why was the answer not both (SA and DA) since both are 6 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

the question is incorrect. 802.1q is a VLAN tag only. The SA / DA are both 6 bytes and part of the standard Ethernet frame.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cisco website, DA is `40bits/5bytes` and SA is `48bits/6bytes`. So, SA is correct answer.
[link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/8021q/17056-741-4.html)

SA—Source Address

The SA field is the source address field of the ISL packet. The field should be set to the `"802.3"` MAC address of the switch port that transmits the frame. It is a `48-bit value.(=6bytes)` The receiving device may ignore the SA field of the frame.

DA—Destination Address

The DA field of the ISL packet is a `40-bit` destination address. This address is a multicast address and is set at `"0x01-00-0C-00-00"` or `"0x03-00-0c-00-00"`. The first `40 bits (=5bytes)` of the DA field signal the receiver that the packet is in ISL format.

Answer (score 0):

YES,
According to Cisco website, DA is 40bits/5bytes and SA is 48bits/6bytes. 
BUT, 
only for InterSwitch-Link (ISL) Frame.

There is no information about size of SA and DA in 802.1Q Frame in the link. 
and the question asks about IEEE 802.1Q. So it may not be correct.